# What do I wrong and I have this TypeError: Cannot set property 'visibility' of undefined?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, error-handling

I have written this HTML code twice in my code:

```
<a class="button-to-hover">LEARN MORE</a>
<div class="buttons"></div>
```

What I wanted to do is make the ".buttons" <div> appear whenever someone hovers over the ".button-to-hover" <a> element. So, I also added this CSS code:

```
.buttons {
   visibility: hidden;
}
```

Finally, I added this Javascipt code:

```
function appearUnderline(underline) {
    this.style.visibility = "visible"; // make the div visible
}

function disappearUnderline(underline) {
    this.style.visibility = "hidden"; // make the div invisible (for when the user stops hovering over the element)
}

function buttonHover(button) {
    this.onmouseover = appearUnderline(this.nextSibling); // when the user hovers, appear the sibling of the element
    this.onmouseout = disappearUnderline(this.nextSibling); // when the user stops hovering, disappear the sibling of the element
}

let buttonNumberOne = document.getElementsByClassName('button-to-hover')[0]; // take the first element you can hover in
let buttonNumberTwo = document.getElementsByClassName('button-to-hover')[1]; // take the second element you can hover in

let button1 = buttonHover(buttonNumberOne); // apply the first button as an argument in buttonHover() function
let button2 = buttonHover(buttonNumberTwo); // apply the second button as an argument in buttonHover() function
```

As you can see, I am a beginner in Javascript. This code doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do all your functions have a parameter when they don't use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking CyberDev's answer and making it a little more flexible and using modern javascript (replace `querySelectorAll` by `getElementsByClassName` and loop over it if you want to support old versions of browsers) :

```js
//Select all your buttons to hover and loop over the list
//With querySelector or querySelectorAll you select elements with css selectors (start with . for a class and # for an id etc)
document.querySelectorAll(".button-to-hover").forEach((btn)=> {
  //Add the action to perform when the mouse is over the button
  btn.addEventListener('mouseover', ()=> {
    btn.nextElementSibling.style.visibility = "visible";
  });
  //Add the action to perform when the mouse is not over the button anymore
  btn.addEventListener('mouseout', ()=> {
    btn.nextElementSibling.style.visibility = "hidden";
  });
});
```

```css
.buttons {
  visibility: hidden;
  }
```

```html
<a class="button-to-hover">LEARN MORE</a>
<div class="buttons">content 1</div>

<div><!--Your page content--></div>

<a class="button-to-hover">LEARN MORE</a>
<div class="buttons">content 2</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`this` accessor is the wrong here.

Here's your solution after fixing `this` issue:

```
function appearUnderline(underline) {
    underline.style.visibility = "visible"; // make the div visible
}

function disappearUnderline(underline) {
    underline.style.visibility = "hidden"; // make the div invisible (for when the user stops hovering over the element)
}

function buttonHover(button) {
    button.onmouseover = appearUnderline(this.nextSibling); // when the user hovers, appear the sibling of the element
    button.onmouseout = disappearUnderline(this.nextSibling); // when the user stops hovering, disappear the sibling of the element
}

let buttonNumberOne = document.getElementsByClassName('button-to-hover')[0]; // take the first element you can hover in
let buttonNumberTwo = document.getElementsByClassName('button-to-hover')[1]; // take the second element you can hover in

let button1 = buttonHover(buttonNumberOne); // apply the first button as an argument in buttonHover() function
let button2 = buttonHover(buttonNumberTwo); // apply the second button as an argument in buttonHover() function
```

You would also need to add a check to ensure that the nextSibling being passed is not null.

Here's a simpler solution to your problem:

```js
var buttonToHover = document.getElementsByClassName("button-to-hover")[0];
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("buttons")[0];
buttonToHover.onmouseover = () => {
buttons.style.visibility = "visible";
}
buttonToHover.onmouseout = () => {
buttons.style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

```css
.buttons {
  visibility: hidden;
  }
```

```html
<a class="button-to-hover">LEARN MORE</a>
<div class="buttons">test</div>
```

There is a concept of [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) that can help you more if you want to solve this with `this`.